# How to get html content of loaded URL into QML WebEngineView?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qwebview

It seems [WebEngineView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html) doesn't provide possibility to access html content loaded by some URL.
It looks like some related features are not yet implemented. [1](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/115773/5) [2](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/120643/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you have to use JavaScript to get the html source. For example, this function will retrieve the html source and log it to the console:

```
function getSource(){
    var js = "document.documentElement.outerHTML";
    webview.runJavaScript(js, function(result){console.log(result);})
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've found that's the best way too for now.